# Evitar que input se salgan del contenedor padre,box-sizing no funciona

Tags: html, css, contenedores

Tengo un problema con un formulario,estoy dandole estilos a los input todo bien,pero estos se salen del formulario,solamente quedan bien si disminuyo el width o el padding,lo intente con el valor "border-box","overflow:hidden" pero no puedo evitar que se salgan,anexo una imagen y el codigo.

Codigo html:

```css
:root {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    font-family: Arial;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.formulario {
    background: #fff;
    width: 500px;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.formulario input {
    display: block;
}

.formulario input[type="text"],
.formulario input[type="email"],
.formulario textarea{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #226fc1;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Formulario-Practica</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="keywords" content="">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/formulario.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <form action="" class="formulario">
        
        <input type="text" id="" placeholder="Nombre">
        <input type="email" placeholder="Correo">
        <textarea name="" id="" placeholder="Mensaje" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        
    </form>
    
    
    </body>
</html>
```

Imagen:
[Input incorrectos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLOwk.jpg)

Comment: Hola Jonatan, para que el código se vea lo puedes hacer seleccionando el código y dándole a Cntrl + K. Lo he editado varias veces pero estás editando mis edit por lo que al final es un bucle cerrado. Te recomiendo que añadas el código con el comando que te he dicho para no sobreescribir un edit con otro como nos está pasando.

Comment: ok ya lo resolví solo una pregunta una imagen como la subo?

Comment: Creo que tienes que tener más puntos para poder subir imágenes. De momento puedes subirla a una plataforma de un tercero y poner aqui el link. ¿Ya resolviste el error o el que aparezca el código?

Comment: ya ,tambien ya subi la imagen gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes que ponerle el `box-sizing:border-box` a los `input`. Al ponerselo al `:root` realmente se lo estarías poniendo a la etiqueta raíz (`html`) y es una [propiedad que no se hereda](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing):

```css
:root {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    font-family: Arial;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.formulario {
    background: #fff;
    width: 500px;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.formulario input {
    display: block;
}

.formulario input[type="text"],
.formulario input[type="email"],
.formulario textarea{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #226fc1;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 16px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Formulario-Practica</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="keywords" content="">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/formulario.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <form action="" class="formulario">
        
        <input type="text" id="" placeholder="Nombre">
        <input type="email" placeholder="Correo">
        <textarea name="" id="" placeholder="Mensaje" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        
    </form>
    
    
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Esto se convirtió en un viejo oeste, hay que ser rápido para publicar una respuesta, jaja, me ganaste

Comment: @JonathanRiveraDiaz Bienvenido al sitio. La respuesta que hayas usado o la que hayas encontrado de más utilidad, puedes márcarla como aceptada pulsando en el tick (✓) que hay en la parte superior izquierda de la misma.

Comment: ok,ya lo realize,quedo solucionado el problema

Comment: @Jorius lo siento :$

Answer (score 2):

Realmente los `inputs` están cogiendo el tamaño que les indicas, el 100% del contenedor.

Sin embargo, tu problema radica en que le estás asignando también un padding de 20px, lo que significa que tendrá un padding superior, inferior, y en cada uno de los lados de 20px.

Por lo tanto, como quieres que el input no se salga del contenedor tendrás que usar la función `calc` para restarle al 100% del contenedor el espacio que se ocupa con el `padding`. Lo que te quedaría así:

```
width: calc(100% - 40px);
```

```css
:root {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    font-family: Arial;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.formulario {
    background: #fff;
    width: 500px;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.formulario input {
    display: block;
}

.formulario input[type="text"],
.formulario input[type="email"],
.formulario textarea{
    width: calc(100% - 40px);
    padding: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #226fc1;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Formulario-Practica</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="keywords" content="">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/formulario.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <form action="" class="formulario">
        
        <input type="text" id="" placeholder="Nombre">
        <input type="email" placeholder="Correo">
        <textarea name="" id="" placeholder="Mensaje" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        
    </form>
    
    
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: me funciono listo